# web3 is not defined

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3-providers

I read other questions like this here but none solved my issue. I have a terminal window on which I ran

```
geth --networkid=4 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --syncmode=light --ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304
```

based on the connect yourself section of the test chain [Rinkeby](https://www.rinkeby.io/).

I also have a node app which has

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

and which I'm running after launching geth.

The terminal launches geth with no issues and outputs `INFO [07-12|15:40:40] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545`. I don't understand why my node app is having trouble connecting to it.

The error is `ReferenceError: web3 is not defined`.

Comment: Hi there. Do you have the `web3` library installed on your system? (e.g. Using Node?)

Comment: Do you need `--rpcapi="web3"` int the geth command?

Comment: I do. I have connected it successfully before with the same app but now wanted to connect it to the Rinkeby chain.

Comment: Just tried now with that (full command: `geth --networkid=4 --rpc --rpcapi="web3" --rpcport 8545 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --syncmode=light --ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304`) and threw the same error.

Comment: I think you're missing the --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" flag?

Comment: try: Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))

Comment: I tried doing both. Added `--rpcaddr "127.0.0.1"` jsut before the `--rpcport` and added `Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("127.0.0.1:8545"))`. Still throws the error.

Comment: try with `var Web3 = require('ethereum_web3.js');` and check if you ahve correctly installed all, i don't know if it is your case or not but [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) i saw this "Include web3.min.js in your html file. (not required for the meteor package)", check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've launched geth as

> geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --syncmode=light
>   --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304
>   --rpc --rpcapi=eth,web3,net,personal,ssh,db,debug console

And have this test file index.js

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

console.log(web3.eth.blockNumber);
```

And it will output the current block on execution `node index.js`

Comment: Ok this seems to work with one caveat: I'm getting the block number back as `0` and that doesn't change. Shouldn't it be downloading the rinkeby blockchain and giving me back increasing block numbers?

Comment: Figured it out, the command should be `geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --syncmode=light --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304 --rpc --rpcapi=eth,web3,net,personal,ssh,db,debug console` (difference is "`.rinkeby`" vs "`rinkeby`"). Block was zero because it wasn't detecting the rinkeby.json (genesis) file. Your answer is correct but for consistency I'd change that because it's how it's laid out in the rinkeby tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: You are right I'd have execute init without the '.' so it worked for me.